# C++ strings passing in function with pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I am not unable to understand how the c++ string pointer are working in the function passing.

```
void print(string str){
     str+=" and sisters."; 
}
int main(){
    string s ="hello brother";
    print(s);
    cout<<s<<endl;
```

}

Output:

```
hello brother
```

and for below function -

```
void print(string &str){
    str+=" and sisters.";
}
int main(){
    string s ="hello brother";
    print(s);
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

Output-

```
hello brother and sisters.
```

I am unable to understand how the pointers are working in case of "string &str" and 
"string str" since I am passing the same string object.

Comment: There's no pointer in the code, it's a pass by value VS pass by reference issue. See [Where should I prefer pass-by-reference or pass-by-value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986341/where-should-i-prefer-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 3):

The ampersand `&` is not a pointer, it means that you will [pass the variable by reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm).

In your first example, you are passing by value, which is essentially a copy. It has a different address in memory, and when the function terminates, it will be destroyed. This is why you only see `hello brother` as the output despite adding `and sisters.` in `print`.

If you were to have:

```
void print(string str){
    str+=" and sisters.";
    cout << "print: " << str << '\n';
}
```

You would see the output

```
print: hello brother and sisters.
```

However, once you exit the function, these changes are destroyed, and this is why you are getting the output you see in `main`.

In the second example, you are passing a reference to where the string `s` in main is stored. It is not a copy, and any changes made in subsequent functions will be visible by `main`. This means that any changes made to the string `s` in `print` will persist once you exit the function, and this is why you see the full string `hello brother and sisters.`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no pointers in any of your programs. Instead, in the second program, the function argument is a *reference*.

A reference references something else, in the case of your example the argument references the variable `s` in the `main` function.

In the first program you pass the argument *by value*, which means it is *copied* and the function only modify its own local copy of the string.

So in the first program you have two different `string` objects, modifying one will not modify the other. In the second program you only have one single `string` object, no copies are made and both variables refer to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

C++ normally passes by value. That is, what is passed to the function is the value of the expression. For example:

```
int add(int i)
{
    i = i + 1;
    return i;
}

int j = 1;
cout << add(j);
```

We should expect this to output 2. But the value of `j` is still 1. We passed the value of `j` (which is one) to `add`. Similarly, `add(8)` will return 9 but not somehow turn that literal 8 in the code into a 9.

However, C++ also supports pass by reference. With pass by reference, we pass the metaphorical location of the object, not its value. For example:

```
int add(int& i)
{
    i = i + 1;
    return i;
}

int j = 1;
cout << add(j)
```

Here, we passed `add` a reference to `j`, not its value. Manipulating the target of that reference manipulates `j`. In this case, `add(8)` would be illegal, and will generate a compiler error.

Note that whether the names of the two variables are the same or not does not matter. I gave them different names just to make it easier to specify which one I was referring to.

Also, none of this has anything to do with pointers. Pointer variables have values that are the address of other objects. They can also be passed either by value or by reference.